# Alternative to IndexedBase

Tags: python, sympy

Consider the following:

```
import sympy
from sympy import *

x = IndexedBase('x')
i = Symbol('i', integer=True)

z = x[i] + x[i+1] + x[i+2]
print z

x[i+1] = 2 # <-- problem

print z
```

at "x[i+1] = 2", i meet "TypeError: 'IndexedBase' object does not support item assignment"
i was hoping to allow updates to the symbolic value of x[i+1], and having "print z" give me the updated symbolic value. it is insufficient for me to replace the x[i+1] term in z, because there might be other expressions using the same x[i+1] term, and i want them to be updated as well.

instead of IndexedBase, what alternatives are recommended since IndexedBase does not support item assignment?

i used IndexedBase because i wanted to represent memory with symbolic references into it.

please let me know how i can rephrase my question and/or needs better to help you help me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

SymPy expressions are not mutable. If you want to change them, you'll need to use a function like `subs` to create a new expression (like `z2 = z.subs(x[i + 1], 2)`).

Comment: yes i think this does what i want.

i will just do z = z.subs(x[i+1], 2)

Comment: This allows you to substitute the entries of `x` one entry at a time. Is there some way to substitute the entire `x` by for example a list of values?

Comment: `subs` also accepts a dictionary of `{old: new}` or a list of `(old, new)` tuples.

Answer (score 1):

maybe what you need to use is something like a lambda. Let's say that you are going to store your values in x. We'll start with 10 values

```
x = range(10)
```

Now define an expression that adds the first and second values of x

```
z = lambda: x[0] + x[1]
```

This lambda will do what you told it every time it is called (which you do by using parentheses after the z:

```
>>> z()
1
```

If you change x[1] then z will give a new answer:

```
>>> z[1] = 42
>>> e1()
42
```

Now if you want a generic range that depends on i you have to create a function of one variable, i:

```
>>> e2 = lambda i: x[i] + x[i+1]
```

If you given this function a value of 0 for i you will get x[0] + x[1]; if you send it a value of 3 for i you will get x[3] + x[4]:

```
>>> e2(0) # x[0] + x[1] = 0 + 42
42
>>> e2(3) # x[3] + x[4] = 3 + 4
7
```

Does this give you some ideas of how to proceed with what you want to do?